# RecyclerView - set item maximum width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, width, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` declared in `.xml` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. I want to use this `CardView` in my `RecyclerView`. But in this `RecyclerView` I would like to set this `CardView` width to `160dp`. How can I do it?

I can't just set `CardView`'s to `android:layout_width="160dp"` because I need it with `match_parent` in another layout.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Create a wrapper layout one set to `match_parent` and the other set to `160dp` -  set the `CardView` to `match_parent` in both cases.

Comment: @MarkKeen You mean to create layout wrapper using `<include>`?